# Add "Donate" to Member

Tags: feature-request, donation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come no option to ‘tip’ answerers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers)

Just an idea and im sure the the developers have come across the idea but i was just bringing up the thought again and looking to see what you guys think.

Now i know that you can add a "Bounty" to a question but why not add a Donate to a member, so if they have helped you out on a regular basis and you feel like you want good karma, you should be able to Donate.

Donations could be limited to amount and donations per day to lessen the security issues but overall it will be a good implementation into the sites ?

For instances if I made a post about a some error im having, and somebody answers the question and also provides with with a great amount of knowledge by talking about the error in detail and taking the time to help me out, I would LOVE to give away 25 / 50 rep here and there.

What you think

Comment: Just to be clear about this -- are you talking about donating rep, or money?

Comment: Im talking about reputation

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use bounties for this, and as such, a redundant system will not (and should not) be implemented.

Comment: But there are some set backs, because bounties can only be issues after 48 hours and questions are usually answered by then, and the fact that you can only have 1 active bounty at any given time!

Answer (score 2):

because points are reputation that shows a level of trust between you and the community.  Giving points away to any random joe will only deteriorate that system of trust.

Comment: Yes but this is already implemented via the bounty.. you can "Award" rep as an incentive to get better answers.

Comment: @RobertPitt - No, that is not the case.  A bounty is a user giving a way their points to a response that best meets their needs.  Donating points for the hell of it is like reputation welfare/charity.  It can only lead to further distrust as you've done nothing to earn reputation.