# How would it be if the SE network kept a "donate" button for their own, for site improvement?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, donation

This question is different from [donating to any specific user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55938/add-donate-to-member).

**If the SE network can receive some extra funding; they can (and should) the following improvements**:

1. Increase the *server strength*, and avoid server [**crash or jam**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289621/why-could-stack-exchange-block-someone-just-for-visiting-64-or-more-tags-on-tago).
2. Increase the *memory space* to safely host more question-answers.
3. Evolving multiple, powerful sync and back-up networks, at different part of world;  so that if the data in the site get damaged anyhow; the sync and back-up network will recover it.
4. Installing more *long-lasting* and *good-quality* *hardwares*.
5. Better *troubleshooting* and *hardware repairing*.
6. Better *feature-update* and *support service.*
7. Better *maintenance* of all aspects of the site.

This  [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92472/can-i-give-a-donation-to-stack-exchange) question; does not tell about requesting a button. Also [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stack-overflow-besides-asking-and-answering) similar question, also not requesting a button; includes a PayPal option or a contribution code; but does not tells about adding a button.

Comment: Found exact dupe, your ideas might be fitting an answer there, to justify such button. (I mean in the "root" request, sorry for the dupe chain.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes my question is quite exact duplicat of that; bot that-one question is again qute wrongly marked as duplicate of [another question,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248243/why-there-is-no-donation-page-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: No, I saw this, and the difference between donate button and donate page is not big enough to justify two separate (and open) requests. I should have closed this as dupe of the donation page request to avoid extra click.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Okay then I don't have any objection. While searching before I've asked; I did not found any of them.

Comment: erm. Has SE ever really had major issues? They seem to run pretty darned well and there's only one SE product I can begin to complain about...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek android app. SE need a developer. They don't hire one because it's not worth the money. Perfect example IMO, and the reason I upvoted this one, while in the past downvoting similar requests.