# Bonus Reputation Awards

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come no option to 'tip' answerers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers)

It would be nice to award a bonus rep to people who go above and beyond the call of duty to answer a question. Almost like a "tip" or "bonus".

This works both ways for me - I've had people go to great lengths to help me:

[Example #1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551495/changing-a-limited-user-account-in-xp-fails)

And I've done the same for other people:

[Example #2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319248/maven-buildnumber-plugin-svn-revision-available-only-when-not-using-format/4320593#4320593)

It would be nice to be able to hand over a few extra rep (from your own) when someone makes a great effort to help you out.

This is different from the bounty system as I believe bounties are when you are trying to get more answers for something where this is when someone **DOES** answer a question - very well.

Comment: Options to donate reputation as a bonus was discussed here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers). The *ultimate* solution was the bounty system but other posts in that thread discuss other ways to *thank* users.