# Can the bounty system be used as a reward system?

Tags: discussion, bounties

[Here's an example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-to-avoid-hotmail-live-rejections-for-legit-large-volume-emailing)

In the case linked to above the question was asked and an accepted answer was chosen. Addtionally, a bounty was placed on the question and also awarded to another user. All of this occurring last July. Today someone liked one of the answers so much they put a bounty on the question just so they could award it to the answerer.

Is this how the bounty system is intended to be used? Is this allowable or acceptable? Isn't voting up the accepted way of showing you like an answer?

Comment: A bounty, by definition, is a reward :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup. That is [accepted usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers/36581#36581).

The bounty system no longer awards an extra 50 reputation (as of [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)).

See more at [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) This states:

> **Can I award a bounty to an old answer?**
>
> Yes, you can award your bounty to any answer on the question. This makes it possible for users to reward particularly good answers with more rep than a standard upvote would provide.

As one needs to wait for 24 hours before being able to assign the bounty to any answer, one might want to [use some comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103956/how-should-bounties-be-categorized/103981#103981) to tell other users that one has already decided who will get the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that answer from Jeff. That sums it up quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Bounties can be used like that, I see no reason to forbid it or discourage it.