# Instant reputation award

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can the bounty system be used as a reward system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78246/can-the-bounty-system-be-used-as-a-reward-system)
>   [How come no option to 'tip' answerers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers)

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957374/writing-set-based-sql-query-without-set-operations-except-intersect). The question itself is probably not very interesting and not very useful for almost anybody else. I really needed to get some feedback. I was surprised that two guys almost immediately dealt with the problem for me and provided two working solutions which shown me another way to achieve it (despite the fact that I didn't used those solution for other reasons).

Now the point - I think the question was complex and it took some time to understand it and provide working solution (which is in big contrast to many highly upvoted answers) but I can't give those guys no more then one upvote and mark one answer. I would like to be able to reward some reputation bonus (transfer my reputation) similar to bounty system (I guess, I can't start a bounty once I accepted the answer) just to show that I very appreciate their involvement.

I know there is some general feeling that if you want to award somebody with more reputation, you can go and upvote his other answers. I'm mostly against this approach because I only upvote answers which I think are good and correct = I must fully understand the question and the answer. It is not always possible especially if I never used related technologies.

**Edit:**

I'm sorry. I din't know that I can start bounty on answered questions. It partially solves the problem but I still don't like the idea that I must wait 24 hours to award the bounty in this scenario.

Comment: *I guess, I can't start a bounty once I accepted the answer* — you guessed wrong: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (Though it's not *instant*, but has a 24 hour wait period. So: write some comment explaining you've already decided who gets the bounty.)

Answer (score 1):

This has already been suggested and declined (can't find exact duplicate but I've seen it in comments here more than once) so it's pretty much closed case.

However, by adding nice comment directed at the person who answered you're giving him something more valuable than 1000 points: gratitude. :)

By the way, you **can** start bounty for questions with accepted answer, I've just now checked it and you can give the bounty to different person than the one with accepted answer. So you can start bounty of 15 points and give to the other person.

From quick check looks like you can even set more than one bounty on the same question!

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea but I think it would have to be restricted so that you could only award up to a set amount, say 50, and that it could only be done once a week. It would save up voting their other answers, which might not be that good, and could trigger the suspicious voting script.

Comment: Sounds like adding a [bounty after accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78246/can-the-bounty-system-be-used-as-a-reward-system) is the correct usage.