# Super-hero recognition

Tags: feature-request

I just spent an hour collaborating with a user (never before encountered, in a different country) who helped with four different jsFiddles and several code examples while helping me resolve my problem.

There was no bounty on the question, this was just someone with great magnanimity of spirit.

Is there any way to request special recognition for such a user? (thecodeparadox)

If not, I would like to suggest an "after the fact" bounty. As with anything else, it would require a basic number of rules so it cannot be abused.

The greatest potential abuse that immediately leaps to mind is that answer givers could extort such a bounty. That is, demand a certain level of bounty before answering a question. As an immediate response to this objection, perhaps a concealed checkbox the donating user must mark, which is never reported to the recipient, can ask if such a thing has happened and moderator justice can ensue?

Anyway, I'd sure like to give this fellow ALL my meager rep on SO for his stellar assistance.

Comment: You can already award a bounty to a specifically good/helpful answer after the fact.

Comment: You need a bit more rep to [set bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), when you earn do what [Mark suggests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147148/162704).

Comment: @BradMace A useful link, but not a duplicate.

Comment: I was sure there was a duplicate too, but couldn't find one. I did come across [Can the bounty system be used as a reward system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78246/can-the-bounty-system-be-used-as-a-reward-system) and [How come no option to 'tip' answerers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the bounty system to award "after the fact" bounties; just select "Reward existing answer" when creating one:

> [image: Bounty dialog with reward existing answer highlighted]

It's subject to all [the terms and conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) regular bounties have.

Comment: Thank you. And here I thought I had conceived something new.

Comment: @gibberish also, you can already flag any instances of attempted "bounty extortion" you come across. Around here, that qualifies as abusive behavior.

Comment: Good point. Hypothetically, though, how would one deal with that if it happens in chat?